# ClassNotFoundException: org/jaxen/NamespaceContext

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dom4j

I am using Maven + tycho-surefire to run some junit-plugin-tests. Whenever i run it i get the following error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.JaxenException
```

Some googling reveals that this means that the jaxen.jar is missing, but if i run it with

`install -X`

It reads:

```
 reference:file:C:\Users\Simon\.m2\repository\p2\osgi\bundle\org.jaxen\1.1.6.v01\org.jaxen-1.1.6.v01.jar[+org/jaxen/*;+org/jaxen/dom/*;+org/jaxen/dom4j/*;+org/jaxen/expr/*;+org/jaxen/expr/iter/*;+org/jaxen/function/*;+org/jaxen/function/ext/*;+org/jaxen/function/xslt/*;+org/jaxen/javabean/*;+org/jaxen/jdom/*;+org/jaxen/pattern/*;+org/jaxen/saxpath/*;+org/jaxen/saxpath/base/*;+org/jaxen/saxpath/helpers/*;+org/jaxen/util/*;+org/jaxen/xom/*;?**/*]
 reference:file:C:\Users\Simon\.m2\repository\.cache\tycho\org.jaxen-1.1.6.v01.jar\jaxen-1.1.6.jar[+org/jaxen/*;+org/jaxen/dom/*;+org/jaxen/dom4j/*;+org/jaxen/expr/*;+org/jaxen/expr/iter/*;+org/jaxen/function/*;+org/jaxen/function/ext/*;+org/jaxen/function/xslt/*;+org/jaxen/javabean/*;+org/jaxen/jdom/*;+org/jaxen/pattern/*;+org/jaxen/saxpath/*;+org/jaxen/saxpath/base/*;+org/jaxen/saxpath/helpers/*;+org/jaxen/util/*;+org/jaxen/xom/*;?**/*]
```

aswell as

```
reference:file:C:/Users/Simon/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.dom4j/1.6.1.v201312101416/org.dom4j-1.6.1.v201312101416.jar
```

Should't this mean that jaxen is available? Is there anything else i can supply to help track down the error?

EDIT:
As requested my pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
           <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
           <version>${tycho-version}</version>
           <configuration>
               <dependency-resolution>
                <optionalDependencies>ignore</optionalDependencies>
                <extraRequirements>
                    <requirement>
                        <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                        <id>org.eclipse.ocl.pivot.uml</id>
                        <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
                    </requirement>
                    <requirement>
                        <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                        <id>org.eclipse.ocl.xtext.completeocl</id>
                        <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
                    </requirement>
                    <requirement>
                        <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                        <id>org.eclipse.ocl.xtext.oclinecore</id>
                        <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
                    </requirement>
                    <requirement>
                        <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                        <id>org.eclipse.ocl.xtext.oclstdlib</id>
                        <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
                    </requirement>
                    <requirement>
                        <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                        <id>org.jaxen</id>
                        <versionRange>1.1.6</versionRange>
                    </requirement>
                    <requirement>
                        <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                        <id>org.jaxen</id>
                        <versionRange>1.1.6</versionRange>
                    </requirement>
                </extraRequirements>
            </dependency-resolution>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

EDIT2:
If i use:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}\lib1234</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

The folder contains:

```
org.jaxen-1.1.6.v01.jar
org.jaxen-1.1.6.v01-jaxen-1.1.6.jar.jar
org.dom4j-1.6.1.v201312101416
```

why is jaxen there twice, does that mean anything?

Comment: Can you please provide your pom file

Comment: added the pom :-) thank you for looking at it

Comment: Can you please provide the entire pom file? [Maven in 5 minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) shows a pom which is familar to me. You only have configured the tycho plugin with your dependencies. I'm not sure if you also need to have an dependency block in your pom file to compile this maven project

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YaeuDY23 full pom, it's kinda large

Comment: I would suggest you to add your requiered dependecies in an `<dependency>` tag. As example: `<dependencies>  <dependency>
    <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
</dependency>` You can give it a try but I'm not quite sure if this fixes the issue

Comment: That did unfortunatly not fix the problem :(

Comment: You have the jaxen requirement two times in your pom i dont think that this lead to the error but I'm not sure.

Comment: thanks, good catch. But didnt fix it :-(